# Verifying the cosine rule

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Verify the following system of linear equations in 
cos A, cos B
, and 
cosC. Triangle cannot be shown.

Then use Cramer’s Rule to solve for 
cosC
, and use the result to verify the Law of Cosines: $c^{2}=a^{2} + b^{2}-2abcos(C)$

Comment: What's the system of linear equations?

Comment: why dont you want to show a triangle.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. Could you please add what the "system of linear equations" is that you're needing to verify? Otherwise we have no way of deriving the cosine rule, because we don't know where you are starting at.

Comment: I'd guess that the system is $$a = b\cos C + c \cos B \qquad b = c \cos A + a \cos C \qquad c = a \cos B + b \cos A$$ These equations are readily verified by dropping a perpendicular from each vertex to the opposite side; drop from $A$ onto $a$ to verify the first equation, etc., by examining the right triangles created.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Triangle]

Looking at the figure, we have $$c=a\cos b+b\cos a$$ and similarly, $$a=b\cos c+c\cos b$$ $$b=a\cos c+c\cos a$$ Cramer's Rule gives $$\cos c=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}b&a &c\\0& c&a\\c&0 &b\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}b&a &0\\0& c&b\\c&0 &a\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{b^2c+a^2c-c^3}{abc+abc}=\frac{b^2+a^2-c^2}{2ab}$$ so $$2ab\cos c=b^2+a^2-c^2$$ and the equation follows.

(Image from Wikipedia, I'm assuming this is the system to which you were referring)